# FFMPEG Command to apply VHS like effect on Video

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding

I want to apply VHS like effect on my video. Please advice me FFMPEG command for same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think **FFMPEG** has no such *VHS* effect/filter. However you could use **AviSynth**
on **FFMPEG**.

1. Download and install **AviSynth**

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/avisynth2/
2. Download an *VHS* effect for **AviSynth**.

   http://www.mediafire.com/download/8crcc3pe23ezcem/AVISynth+VHS+Effect+v13.3.3.zip

   Source:

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osUvH8PRk3g
3. Write your **AviSynth** script, just a plain text file with name '*Script.avs*'.

   ```
   DirectShowSource??("C:\your source video file.avi")
   TextSub??("C:\your source video subtitle.ass")
   ```
4. Put the script file in the same folder as the source video, then run **FFMPEG** with the corresponding parameters.

   ```
   ffmpeg.exe -i "script.avs" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "C:\Output video.avi"
   ```

Note: The steps provided are theorically, taken from various sources. I didn't tested at all.